# adding a custom post type as a sub-menu of another existing page menu

Tags: wordpress, ads

I added a page menu in admin panel via this code and it works fine.

```
add_menu_page('Ads Dashboard', 'Ads Dashboard', 'administrator', 'adverts', 'advert_admin_options');
```

And now I need to add/register post type under this menu, but it doesn't work properly. Seems something is wrong in my code here is my whole code for both:

```
function add_ads_post_type(){ 
    register_post_type('ads', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Adverts', 'theme'),
            'singular_name' => __('Adverts', 'theme'),
            'menu_name' => __('Adverts', 'theme'),
            'add_new' => __('Add Advert Item', 'theme'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Advert item', 'theme'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Advert item', 'theme'),
            'new_item' => __('New Advert item', 'theme'),
            'view_item' => __('View Advert item', 'theme'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Advert items', 'theme'),
            'not_found' => __('No Advert found', 'theme'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Advert items found in Trash', 'theme'),
        ),
    'public' => TRUE,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'ads', 'with_front' => false),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
        'show_in_menu' => 'admin.php?page=adverts'
    )); 
}
function advert_add_to_menu() {
    if (is_admin()) {
        add_menu_page('Ads Dashboard', 'Ads Dashboard', 'administrator', 'adverts', 'advert_admin_options');
        add_submenu_page('adverts', 'Ads', 'Ads', 10, 'ads-list', 'add_ads_post_type' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'advert_add_to_menu');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : post type is 'ads'

```
//REMOVE MENU


function remove_menu_CPT_ads() {  
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=ads' );  
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_CPT_ads' );
function add_my_menu(){
 add_submenu_page('adverts', 'Ads', 'Ads', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug','Your_function');
}
 add_action('admin_menu','add_my_menu');
 function Your_function(){   
     wp_redirect(admin_url().'/edit.php?post_type=ads');
     exit;
 }
 function add_ob_start(){
    if(is_admin()){
     ob_start();
    }
 }
 add_action('admin_init', 'add_ob_start');
```

Comment: no via this code, it shows 'custom page inside custom post type menu' in general page, but I want to add custom post type as sub menu @vrajesh

Comment: now I changed my code like this, 'show_in_menu'  => 'adverts', and add_submenu_page('adverts', 'Ads', 'Ads', 'manage_options', 'adverts-list', 'add_ads_post_type' ); it adds Ads sub menu under main page but doesn't create post type just page, what do you think? @vrajesh

Comment: I have only one post type (ads). See I have a page menu (admin.php?page=adverts) and wanted to add post type under it. @vrajesh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90399/discussion-between-aidaghazaryan-and-vrajesh).

Answer (score 3):

Why so hard guys?
Just use `show_in_menu` arg. like: `'show_in_menu' => adverts'` in case of custom menu element where `adverts` is an menu uid.

If you want to place into already existed menu element like under another post type menu block then you can use `'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type={CTP}'`,

https://imtiazrayhan.com/multiple-custom-post-types-menu-section/

I know it is old, but maybe this save some one time :)

Comment: I can confirm that this works on WordPress 5.9. The menu uid in my case was just the menu slug.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question and the approved answer does work, but I found the following blog post very helpful.
https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-add-wordpress-cpt-admin-menu-as-sub-menu/

For a quick start, use the following. Read the full blog to get the highlighting/active page to work:

1. show_in_menu args MUST false

   ```
   register_post_type( 'your-cpt', array(
   'description'           => '',
   'public'                => true,
   'show_ui'               => true,
   'show_in_menu'          => false, /* Do not show admin menu */
   [...] 
   ) );
   ```
2. Add Submenu to parent

   ```
   add_submenu_page(
       'Ads_Dashboard',              // parent slug
       'Your CPT Title',             // page title
       'Sub Menu Title',             // sub-menu title
       'edit_posts',                 // capability
       'edit.php?post_type=your-cpt' // your menu menu slug
   );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
    add_menu_page('Page title', 'Top-level menu title', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-handle', 'my_magic_function');
    add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-handle', 'Page title', 'Sub-menu title', 'manage_options', 'my-submenu-handle', 'my_magic_function');
    ?>
```

Here's an example of adding an option page under a custom post type menu block (see also here):

```
<?php 
add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=wiki', 'Options', 'Options', 'manage_options', 'wiki-options', array(&$this, 'options_page') );
 ?>
```

Please see this for more information : https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus